# How to change the title text of a SVG path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML file, I have an SVG with the following path syntax:

```
<path id="path0">
    <title>title text</title>
</path>
```

Using JavaScript, how do I dynamically change `title text`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelector` with the query `'#path0 > title'` to find the title element that is a direct descendant of the `#path0` element.

Use the `textContent` property of the path node to set a new title value.

```js
const title = document.querySelector('#path0 > title');
title.textContent = 'I am a path';
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="path0">
    <title>title text</title>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: OP asks to dynamically change title text

Comment: @PA. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I must have misread.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` to select title inside path.
`'#path0>title'` where `#` select id with value `path0`,
 `>` means direct child of `path0`, 
 `textContent` gives you excess to the text portion pf title.

```
document.querySelector('#path0>title').textContent = "New Content";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Just updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select the parent, and may be save to a variable:

`const parent = document.getElementById('path0');`

Then you have to get the inside element what's called a children:

`const children = parent.children[0];`

Or this in one step:

`const childElement = document.getElementById('path0').children[0];`

Then you can change the text inside it like this:

`childElement.textContent = "Your text here!";`

An other **more coincise** one liner **version** would look like this:

`document.querySelector('#path0>title').textContent = "Your text here!";`

Here you select the direct descendant of the lement marked with id="path0", then you change the text content whit the .textContent command. Note that in this case you don't need to use a variable.

You can insert your chosen code in the end of your html file between script tags like this:

```
//...html  content
<script>
  document.querySelector('#path0>title').textContent = "Your text here!";
</script>
```

I hope it helps.